# Как обойтись без index.html для отправки запроса. GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish

Например у меня есть сервер приложений с таким вот сервлетом:
http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2014/03/writing-and-deploying-simple-web.html

Вопрос смогу ли я отправить Post запрос используя скажем PostMan? Какой будет урл? Нужен ли вообще index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, Post запрос можно отправить.
Урл будет тот что в конфигурации сервлета, в данном примере:

```
@WebServlet(name = "PersonServlet", urlPatterns = {"/PersonServlet"})
```

`/PersonServlet`  будет вашим URL

index.html не нужен.